# Storing Japanese characters in Teradata

Tags: sql, ssis, character, teradata

I have a SSIS package that pushes data from a SQL database to a Teradata database.  In my SQL database, I have a particular table that stores Japanese characters, which are read in from a file (encoded in UTF 8 format).  The column that holds this data is of type "nvarchar".  Currently, I have no issues viewing the characters in SQL.  However, when I run my package these characters are displaying as junk in teradata.  Even if I do a simple insert with Japanese characters, I cannot view the data.  The column in teradata is of type varchar (CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC).  I know there is no nvarchar datatype in teradta. Any thoughts on how to store these characters?

Comment: What tool are you using to retrieve the data from Teradata? 

If it is SQL Assistant the default font may not support UNICODE encoded text. You may need to change your font to something like `Lucida Sans Unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem and i got it resolved by doing the following.

In Teradata SQL Assistant -- go to `Tools` >> `Define ODBC Data Source` >> A dialog box opens - there you select your User DSN name and click on `"Configure"` >> another box opens - at the bottom set Session Character Set to `UTF8` >> click OK and close all the windows.

Now reconnect and you will be able to see other languages.